# date.getHourOfDay() is giving strange results in aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am indexing some events and trying to get unique hours but the *terms aggregation* is giving weird response . I have the following query.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "City": [
              "Chicago"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "eventDate": {
              "gte": "2018-06-22",
              "lte": "2018-06-22"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Hours": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['eventDate'].date.getHourOfDay()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query produces following response.

```
"buckets": [
        {
          "key": "19",
          "doc_count": 12
        },
        {
          "key": "9",
          "doc_count": 7
        },
        {
          "key": "15",
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "16",
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "20",
          "doc_count": 4
        },
        {
          "key": "12",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "6",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "8",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "10",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "11",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
```

Now I changed the range to get the events for past one month

> { 
>                     "range": {
>                       "eventDate": {
>                         "gte": "2018-05-22",
>                         "lte": "2018-06-22"
>                       }
>                     }
>                   }

and the response I got was

> ```
> "Hours": {
>       "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
>       "sum_other_doc_count": 1319,
>       "buckets": [
>         {
>           "key": "22",
>           "doc_count": 805
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "14",
>           "doc_count": 370
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "15",
>           "doc_count": 250
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "21",
>           "doc_count": 248
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "16",
>           "doc_count": 195
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "0",
>           "doc_count": 191
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "13",
>           "doc_count": 176
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "3",
>           "doc_count": 168
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "20",
>           "doc_count": 159
>         },
>         {
>           "key": "11",
>           "doc_count": 148
>         }
>       ]
>     }
> ```

As you can see I got buckets with **key 6,8,9,10 and 12** in the response of first query but not in the second query which is very strange as documents returned by first query is a small subset of the second query. Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing out the size of `terms` aggregator, by default is 10. Set it to 24 to get desired results. Refer this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size

Comment: Thanks for your help Chandra!! That worked after setting the size to 24.